# How to add multiple many-to-many fields in one form with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a form that's got the following association:

**Course.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
```

**Skill.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

what I wanna do is allow the person who wants to add a new `Course` select all the skills from his selected category and be able to add them by using a checkbox. In the view I've done like so:

**VIEW**

```
<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <% @skills.each do |s| %>
    <%= f.check_box :value => s.id %> <%= s.title %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Sadly this isn't working and I get the following error:

```
undefined method `{:value=>9}' for #<Course:0x00000004ce0208>
```

could you please help on finding a fix for my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Try giving it like this `<%= check_box_tag "course[skill_ids][]", s.id, current_skill_ids.include?(s.id) %>`

Comment: Before doing that you gave to set it like this `<% current_skill_ids = @course.skill_ids %>`.

Comment: That shows me them alright, thanks. But they're not being saved in the `courses_skills` table, do you have an idea what could prevent them from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Rails 4** there's now an awesome [**`collection_check_boxes`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) form helper method.

From the [**Rails API docs**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes):

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your setting, it might be something like this:

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :skill_ids, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The cool thing about `collection_check_boxes` is that is optionally [takes a block](
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) which let's you customize the generated markup (e.g. for styling purposes):

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
  b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.check_box + b.text }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this code:

**For Rails 3.***

```
<%= check_box_tag "course[skill_ids][]", s.id, s.title %>
```

**For Rails 4.***
As mentioned in comment, Rails 4 introduced [collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes), so your code may look like:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:course, :skill_ids, Skills.all, :id, :title) %>
```

See documentation for check_box_tag: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

How to handle HABTM in Rails I recommend this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised), or the code is available [here](http://patrickperey.com/railscast-017-habtm-checkboxes/).

Comment: That's a good way for building collection check boxes manually in Rails 3. In Rails 4, a new [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) form helper has been introduced that does exactly this thing. Think you might like that :)