# Uninitialized constant Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

Basically I'm using `many-to-many` relationship with `through` to combine `Skill` and `Course` models. So it looks like this:

**Course**

```
has_many :course_skills
has_many :skills, through: :course_skills
```

**Skill**

```
has_many :course_skills
has_many :courses, through: :course_skills
```

**CourseSkills**

```
belongs_to :skill
belongs_to :course
```

And I'd like to be able to add many skills to courses so the view looks like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :skill, "Skills" %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :skill_ids, Skill.all, :id, :title %>
  </div>
```

When I didn't have this setup, but only used `belongs_to` and `has_many` it worked, but now I'm getting an error that says: `uninitialized constant Course::CourseSkill` and points me to the line where the `collection_check_boxes` are. So what am I doing wrong? Also I was folloing this previous post if that makes my point more clear: [How to add multiple many-to-many fields in one form with Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814740/how-to-add-multiple-many-to-many-fields-in-one-form-with-rails-4)

Comment: Your model name should be `CourseSkill`.. not `CourseSkills`. As per the Rails convention `has_many :course_skills`, translated to the model name as `CourseSkill`..Look the doc [The name of the other model is pluralized when declaring a has_many association.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association). Now read it reverse way..

Comment: Is the third model actually called `CourseSkills`? It should be `CourseSkill`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit yup, that was it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP agreed in the comment, with my suggestion in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835659/uninitialized-constant-rails-4#comment36675899_23835659), I am taking it into the answer -

Your model name should be `CourseSkill`, not `CourseSkills`. As per the Rails convention `has_many :course_skills`, translated to the model name as `CourseSkill`..Look the doc [The name of the other model is pluralized when declaring a has_many association.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association). Now read it reverse way..

Comment: I have one more issue now - it's not saving anything to the course_skills database table, do you have an idea why is that?

Comment: @Xeen There can be lots of reasons for not saving, one is *validations*, sometimes reason could be *hooks*.. Just looking at this part, not possible to track it.. If any error you are getting, do backtrace, and find it out..